# Why second thread with ContinueWith option is not waiting for first thread's end?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Why second thead started by line

```
var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith( .. )
```

is not waiting for first thread's end? This is printout proving that the new thread is not waiting for the first one's end:

> Starting main thread 1
>  Starting ContinueWith thread 2
>   0  0  0
>   
>   Ending ContinueWith thread 2  
>   ContinueWith thread is
>   finished!  
>   Starting child thread 3 
>   Ends child thread 3 
>   
>   Starting child thread 2  
>   Ends child thread 2  
>  
>   Starting child thread 1  
>   Ends child thread 1

Code:

```
public static void AttachTasksToMain()
        {
            Task<Int32[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting main thread 1");
                var results = new Int32[3];
                new Task(() => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting child thread 1");
                    results[0] = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("Ends child thread 1");
                }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

                new Task(() => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting child thread 2");
                    results[1] = 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Ends child thread 2");
                }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

                new Task(() => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting child thread 3");
                    results[2] = 2;
                    Console.WriteLine("Ends child thread 3");
                }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

                //this thread finishes when all child-thread are finished!
                return results;
            });
            //parent.Wait();

            var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(parentTask =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting ContinueWith thread 2");
                foreach (int i in parentTask.Result)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);

                Console.WriteLine("Ending ContinueWith thread 2");
            });

            finalTask.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("ContinueWith thread is finished!");

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `Task.Run`.  This starts the task with `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach`.

A simple change to using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and the problem is solved.  That's because the default here is `TaskCreationOptions.None`.

[See here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) for an in depth discussion of the difference.